# Rhino - dead in the water?

Tags: rhino

I'm looking to add scripting into my Java app and JavaScript would be a great language choice. My concern though is the Rhino project and its future.

While Groovy/Jruby etc have seen constant updates, and engines like V8 and SpiderMonkey make continuous and significant performance boosts; Rhino languishes with its last release in March '09.

I've seen some work on hacking Rhino:

- http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/pres/201009-ThunderingRhinos/pres.html
- http://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/project/google/gsoc2011/rohit_mullangi/37001

But nothing solid about actually merging this code into the project and getting an active committer community around it.

Does anyone have any insight into the Rhino road map?

Is there any plan for example to bring invokedynamic to the Rhino world?

Or is Rhino's destiny to simply become less and less relevant as time goes on?

All insight appreciated!

Comment: +1: I'd vote to reopen if I could; this is an interesting question that I wish I could read an answer for! And I don't think it's too open ended.

Comment: @Vuntic It was re-asked on the more appropriate Programmers.SE: [Does Rhino have a future?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/81620/8)